How do I find the standard deviation of the original data with my optimal curve fit in Python?
Let us say I have a broadly linear data sample space. I fit a line through the data.
I want the standard deviation of the data from the modelled line.
The pcov matrix provides the standard deviation of the parameters. But I want the standard deviation of the dataset (y) from the curve fit (y_model). Is there any direct way to get that apart from calculating it in Python like this?
stdev = np.std(f_model(x_data,popt[0],popt[1]) - y_data)


Are you familiar with residuals? MSE, RMSE?

That seems like a pretty short way of calculating it. If you want something slightly shorter, you could use stdev = np.std(f_model(x_data, *popt) - y_data) . But I doubt anything's shorter than that.

Lets say you have a linear dataset:
import numpy as np
import numdifftools as nd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize, stats

def model(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b

np.random.seed(12345)
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 30)
p = (2., 3.)
y = model(x, *p)
s = 0.25 * np.ones_like(y)
n = s * np.random.normal(size=y.size)
yn = y + n

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(model, x, yn, sigma=s, absolute_sigma=True)
# (array([2.00095541, 3.08452241]),
#  array([[5.84677424e-03, 1.04805847e-11],
#         [1.04805847e-11, 2.08333335e-03]]))

You can estimate uncertainty on y by propagating parameters uncertainties.
def error(x, p, Cp):
    
    def proxy(r):
        return model(x, *r)
    
    gradient = nd.Gradient(proxy)
    
    def propagation(J):
        return J @ Cp @ J.T
    
    Cy = np.apply_along_axis(propagation, 1, gradient(p))
    sy = np.sqrt(Cy)
    
    return sy

sy = error(x, popt, pcov)
# array([0.08905115, 0.08456633, 0.08017755, 0.07590145, 0.0717582 ,
#        0.06777217, 0.06397273, 0.06039513, 0.05708108, 0.05407907,
#        0.05144375, 0.04923403, 0.04750934, 0.04632389, 0.04571964,
#        0.04571964, 0.04632389, 0.04750934, 0.04923403, 0.05144375,
#        0.05407907, 0.05708108, 0.06039513, 0.06397273, 0.06777217,
#        0.0717582 , 0.07590145, 0.08017755, 0.08456633, 0.08905115])

Which can be used to assess confidence interval where model lies if parameters varies:

